# Avoiding mysql filesort

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-key

I have a client running a php photo gallery (on php 5.5, mysql 5.5, using myisam tables) that uses the directory tree method. Unfortunately, some of the queries in their gallery application is demanding horribly long filesorts. The offending query:

```
SELECT `name`, `slug` 
FROM `db_table` 
WHERE `left_ptr` <= '914731' 
  AND `right_ptr` >= '914734' 
  AND `id` <> 1 
ORDER BY `left_ptr` ASC
```

There are indexes on id, left_ptr and right_ptr, but according to the EXPLAIN, none of them are being used in the query.

I heard that creating a composite index (on the 'condition' columns) would make things faster, but does that apply to this case? The last condition is really but an 'anything but 1' clause, so would a composite index apply to that, too? Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: It seems none of those three filtering predicates are selective enough. How many rows (percentage) does each condition **separately** select? The most efficient index usage occurs when using equality predicates; but you don't have any: you have inequalities and difference only.

Comment: Try to add a composite index on (left_ptr, right_ptr)

Comment: @TheImpaler: unfortunately, that's the way it was programmed. By what I can tell from the method, the directory tree left/right numbers can change pretty well to anything depending on the hierarchy size and complexity, so it is hard to set limits IMHO. But I completely see where you're coming from.

Comment: How many times have I said that "filesort" is not that evil?  Perhaps 89 times:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+user%3A1766831+filesort

Comment: The "left-right" schema is clever, but does not scale well.  Hmmm... Maybe I need to blog about how to replace it.  But then, 8.0 has "recursive CTEs" which make the task straightforward (sort of).

Comment: Composite keys are useful when no more than the last column in the key is tested with a "range".  All of your tests are ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a composite index on `(left_ptr, right_ptr)` should make this query run better.

[MySQL will only use one index per query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html). It's likely not using any single index because it's determined no single index would be much faster than a full table scan. For example, `id <> 1` is every row but the first, so just do a full table scan. The other two filters depend on how the data is distributed, but if it doesn't filter a significant portion of the table it won't use an index.

A composite index on `(left_ptr, right_ptr)` should make this query run better. Don't bother with `id`, as above `id <> 1` only filters one row.

MySQL can use the first column of a composite index alone, so this composite index also replaces the one on `left_ptr` alone

Comment: Thank you. If a run a query alone, it picks up the new composite key quite well (no more sorting), but when I run multiple queries (threads), I get some interesting behaviour: it uses the `right_ptr`key rather than the composite one (and uses filesort again).

There are indexes on Id (Unique), left_ptr, right_ptr, then the composite leftright_ptr on the latter two columns (all listed in 'explain' as 'available keys').

Comment: An additional question: does the fact that mysql can use the composite in lieu of the left_ptr mean that I can remove the left_ptr index? If I removed the right_ptr index as well (it is only used as a comparison to left_ptr), would this oblige mysql to use leftright_ptr every time?

Comment: @JosefM.Schomburg Yes, you can remove the `left_ptr` index, MySQL will use the `left_ptr, right_ptr` index. I do not recommend removing the `right_ptr` index as that leaves MySQL with no options for queries which only filter by `right_ptr`. Instead, try using an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: @JosefM.Schomburg - For a small `914731`, one composite index; for large, the other.  Have both, and get rid of the single-column indexes.

Comment: In the first queries after implementing the new 'leftright_ptr' composite index, it would use this for sorting, but at present it has fallen back to using the 'primary' ('id') index.